# How to create a function in script so that the column of currency data displays the currency in the email generated?

Tags: javascript, format, currency

I want the total in parameter2 to be in currency format in the generated email.

I have tried to use Number Format but continue to receive an error stating my range can not be found

```
function sendArticleCountEmails() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Send-Emails"));
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:F5");
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var rowData = data[i];
        var emailAddress = rowData[1];
        var recipient = rowData[0];
        var message1 = rowData[2];
        var message2 = rowData[3];
        var parameter2 = rowData[4];
        var message3 = rowData[5];

        //Number Format
        var dataRange = sheet.getRange("rowData[4]");
        column.setNumberFormat('$');

        var message = 'Dear Customer ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1 + ' ' +
            message2 + ' ' + parameter2 + ' ' + message3;
        var subject = 'Your YTD Sales';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Below is an example of the email generated. I would like the 45000 to read $45,000

Dear Customer John Doe,

Customer #123456789 sales expectations were $50,000. Customer had 45000 in
actual sales.

Comment: You're trying to getRange for value "rowData[4]" which doesn't seem to be a valid arguement. I assume this is google sheets? Their documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)), looks like you can specify row/column groups. Passing a string representing an object field is not a supported arguement